# Use of Apple flash storage for data

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, flash-memory

I am Android Developer and I am working on Apple machines. Recently I bought a MacBook Pro with 128 GB flash storage but without HDD. The use of the laptop will be only for work and for surfing in the internet. Any multimedia will be stored on a external disc but all the stuff from work I want to be stored in the flash storage. Except of Android Studio, I also use some other tools-frameworks like MAMP, Postgres, gimp etc.

Will be a problem for the laptop and its flash drive if I will not use any external HDD and all the job will be stored in the flash storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, you can use the flash SSD inside your MacBook exactly like you would use an internal HDD. The noticeable differences are that it is smaller capacity that a typical HDD, but also much, much faster and more power-efficient.

The only thing you should avoid are actions that intentionally stress the drive, like read/write speed tests. Running heavy-duty applications and servers should be no problem (provided you only need 128 GB of space).